How can I fetch the title and start page number from the table of content?
I have this file created in MS-Word. I wanted to get the start page number and the title from the table of content.
But I could only grab the Title, and got stuck on how to fetch the start page number.
import docx
from docx.oxml.text.paragraph import CT_P
from docx.text.paragraph import Paragraph

def extract_table_of_contents(file_path):
    
    document = docx.Document(file_path)
    body_elements = document._body._body

    rs = body_elements.xpath('.//w:r')    
    table_of_content = [r.text for r in rs if r.style == "Hyperlink"]

    print(table_of_content)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    file_path = "Contents.docx"
    extract_table_of_contents(file_path)


Output: ['Heading 1', 'Heading 2', 'Heading 3']
How can I fetch the title and start page number from the table of content?
